# SQL Server from command line as mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I view SQL Server databases created from command line? In mysql it can be done like

```
C:> mysql -u name -p(password)
```

But I don't know what default (root) username and password I can use to enter

```
C:> sqlcmd -U xxx -P xxx
```

what is xxx I should use ?

Comment: do you have windows authentication turned on?

Comment: you really should ask your dba

Comment: what do you mean ? Please explain more I don't understand

Comment: sql server can use windows authentication to login. theres a switch to use that.

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlcmd` utility should work for users without administrative rights. In addition to specifying the user name and the password of your non-admin user you need to specify the database to which your user name has access:

```
C:> sqlcmd -U <non-admin-username> -P <non-admin-password> -d db_name
```

Alternatively, you can "piggyback" on the windows login that has access to your database by specifying the `-E` option:

```
C:> sqlcmd -E
```

Windows authentication should be turned on for this to work (try this out, or ask your DBA).